# lots of warnings on webserver using objectbox

Tags: embedded-jetty, spark-java, objectbox

I am using a SparkJava (basically Jetty) web server behind an nginx proxy with ObjectBox.

I'm starting to notice a lot of

```
Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 213).
Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 213).
Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 213).
Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 213).
Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 213).
Hint: use closeThreadResources() to avoid finalizing recycled transactions (initial commit count: 213).
038-22:43:52.3260 [WARN ] Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread 'java')
038-22:43:52.5815 [WARN ] Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread 'java')
038-22:43:52.5815 [WARN ] Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread 'java')
038-22:43:52.5815 [WARN ] Destroyed recycled transaction from non-owner thread 'java'
038-22:43:52.5820 [WARN ] Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread 'java')
038-22:43:52.5820 [WARN ] Destroyed recycled transaction from non-owner thread 'java'
038-22:43:52.5821 [WARN ] Skipping low-level close for read-only cursor (non-creator thread 'java')
```

warnings, in my logs, and I'm thinking of ways around this.

What I've seen suggested, is possibly to call `closeThreadResources()` as suggested in the hints, possibly after each call has finished. However, I'm no expert on Jetty and not sure if each thread is killed or reused possibly. Maybe calling `closeThreadResources()` might break if threads are reused? Plus, I have multiple ObjectBox boxes, so I'd probably have to either remember which boxes have been used, or call `closeThreadResources()` on all of them. Not perfect, but doable.

Then there is also the possible reuse of queries, that might fix things, after reading https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/753#issuecomment-525314808. I can potentially redo most of my code to create the queries once, then set the parameter values when they're used. How thread safe is this, when being used by a webserver? i.e. if i change the value of a query to use it, and it's already being used by another thread, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you likely want to do is to call `closeThreadResources()` once you are done with a web request from the thread serving it. This works fine with threads pools, which are also used by web servers. You can do this for all requests with e.g. servlet filters, but not sure if there are better approaches these days to do that.

Some background: each thread using ObjectBox "caches" some resources (thread local). The best way to clean up after a thread is "done" (at least for now, e.g. served the eb request) with ObjectBox, it to call `closeThreadResources()`. Once that thread is back (e.g. from thread pool) it will simply allocate the resources it needs again.

Queries: yes you can reuse them, but ensure to lock e.g. the Query object while you query as you might race with other threads serving requests too.

Comment: 1) when you say Lock do you mean standard Java lock with synchronised etc? I've never touched that stuff so I'll look into it.
2) ok, I'll try and do the `closeThreadResources()` thing. I don't really know what a servlet filter is, but if you think it should be ok with the natural Threading the web server does I'll give it a whirl.
Thanks

Comment: 1) yes, good old `synchronized` 2) if you don't have a lot of requests, you could also call it manually at the end of each request

Comment: I have 20-30 endpoints which I think are what a servlet filter is (after a quick googling). I think I can set a `post()` action that happens after every call to the web server. I think I'll add it there and just run it on every box (I have about 10). That way I can be certain of cleaning up every box regardless of if it was used. I think that should be clean enough, plus doesn't mean I have to call it per specific box in all 30 endpoints, cos that will be a real pain to code. Lazy!

Comment: `boxStore.closeThreadResources()` should take care of all Box instances

Comment: oooooooh, nice!

Comment: Just to follow up, since doing it at a boxStore level, I've had no warnings of either type. Thanks @markus